# Django form - Can I create an object without saving it?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an object (*myModel*) which i want to create according to a form(*myModelForm*), I also want that the object would be related to a *requiered* **ForeignKey** object (Group) which i want to decide by myself.(i.e, don't want it to be in the form.

So if I try to use **form.save()** i get an error. is there a way i can add Group ForeignKey (in view) before i use **save()**?

My code looks something like this:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    myGroup = ForeignKey(Group)
    normal_field1 = TextField()
    ...
    normal_field2 = TextField()


class myModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = myModel
       fields = [normal_field1,noraml_field2]
```

muchas gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `commit=False` to create the item without persisting it to the database.

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.myGroup= whatever
    obj.save()
```